# what is this kind of initialization and assignment called?

Tags: c++, initialization, variable-assignment

i know this

```
int value1 = 1; // is copy initialization
double value2(2.2); // is direct initialization
char value3 {'c'}; // is uniform initialization
int value4 = {5}; // is initializer list
value4 = 6; // is copy assignment
```

I'm just curious, what this is called?

```
int value5 = (3);
value5 = (4);
value5 = {5};
```

Comment: Isn't it copy assignment for 4, 5 and copy initialization for 3?

Comment: There are only two main syntactic forms of initialization, namely copy initialization and direct initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For

```
int value5 = (3);
```

it's [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)

> T object = other;     (1)
>
> 1) when a named variable (automatic, static, or thread-local) of a non-reference type T is declared with the initializer consisting of an equals sign followed by an expression.

---

For:

```
value5 = (4);
value5 = {5};
```

It's direct assignment.

[Assignment operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment)

> copy assignment operator replaces the contents of the object a with a copy of the contents of b (b is not modified). For class types, this is a special member function, described in copy assignment operator.
>
> For non-class types, copy and move assignment are indistinguishable and are referred to as direct assignment.

Answer (score -2):

`int value5 = (3);` and `value5 = (4);` is still copy assignment, since the right-hand side is simply evaluated to `3` and `4` respectively.

On the other hand `value5 = {5};` is copy initializer list.

Comment: **–1** assignment is not initialization.